# Iterating over a list of custom classed objects

Tags: c++, iteration

So I've looked up the issue and used the given solutions and came up with this piece of code:

```
list<Projectile*>::iterator bullet;
for(bullet = bullets.begin(); bullet != bullets.end(); bullet++)
    .
            .
            .               
}
```

Problem: No operator '=' matches these operands. The same with != ...
I'm clueless as to why :/

Comment: What is the type of `bullets` in that context?

Comment: I also suggest you changing the incremental part of your loop from "bullet++" to "++bullet", it may be faster in some cases, it's a good idea to get this practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least based on your comment, you're attempting to use a `list<Projectile *>::iterator` where a `list<Projectile>::iterator` is needed.

As an aside, 1) `list` is rarely the best choice of containers, and 2) most of the time, you're better off iterating through a collection with a pre-packaged algorithm instead of writing a loop.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. As for the choice of using a list. I read the documentation of Vectors, Deqeues and Lists and that seemed most appropriate to use since I'm going to be removing random items from the collection at any given time and also constantly dropping new ones in. What do you mean by a pre-packaged algorithm in this case ?

Comment: Do you need to maintain order when you add/remove items? If not, with a vector, you can add to the end, and when/if you need to remove from the middle, you can swap the item with the last one, then remove it from the end. A pre-packaged algorithm would be something like `std::for_each` or `std::transform`.

Comment: I don't care about the order but this piece of text coming from c++ docs "For operations that involve inserting or removing elements at positions other than the end, they perform worse than deques and lists, and have less consistent iterators and references than lists." told me to use a list rather than a vector. As for for_each, well, I just jumped into OpenGl and the code looks so 'confusing' that I want to keep it simple at this point :)

Comment: @qiuntus: Sounds like some rather dated advice. The problem is fairly simple: list isn't very cache-friendly, so on modern processors it's often (quite a bit) slower than a vector (for one example) even in cases where it should theoretically be the best choice.